# Manga where the villainess was executed and then goes back in time and apologizes to the male lead, whom she bullied

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I'm  trying to find this manga where the villainess was executed and then goes back in time, but not before she bullied the male lead, so she apologizes to him.

The male lead's father left on a ship and no one thought he would return, so the female lead and her family abuse him. Then his dad returns and his status rises, so he gets revenge on them and she goes back in time.

She had blonde hair. I think he had black hair?

Comment: Hi. Can you tell us anything more about the plot or characters? We could potentially ID the story with the information you've already provided, but it would be nice to have a bit more to go on.

Comment: The male leads father left on ship and no one thought he would return so the female lead and her family abuse him his dad returns and his status raises so he gets revenge on them and she goes back in time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[I Tamed the Male Lead Who Tried to Kill Me](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-tamed-the-male-lead-who-tried-to-kill-me)***...?

> Latia's family took in Karshian when his father went on a maritime expedition, but after rumors go around that he's dead, they treat him like a parasite. Egged on by her sadistic parents and desperate for their approval, Latia bullies Karshian relentlessly. However, when Karshian's father returns as a national hero and powerful duke, Karshian gets his revenge by executing Latia's entire family! As she recalls her last moments, she realizes that her family had been lying to her all along. So when she's thrown back into the past, she's determined to prevent her death and treat Karshian right this time. But this won't be easy when Karshian distrusts Latia's every move. Will Latia be able to win over Karshian and turn the tables on her family this time around, or is she doomed to die once more?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "I Tamed the Male Lead Who Tried to Kill Me."]

The father of the male lead, Karshian Laumdiselle, was a poor count who went on a maritime expedition to avoid going bankrupt. He was very successful in this regard, opening up the world's first maritime trade route and incorporating the pirates who were a nuisance to the Empire into the Navy. Upon his return to the Empire, his deeds were acknowledged and he was rewarded with the title of duke.

During the three-plus years that Karshian's father was away for, though, Karshian lived with the family of the female lead, Latia Gladelise, who assumed that Karshian's father would die out at sea and consequently treated Karshian as an unwelcome parasite. Latia -- who, like Karshian, was a child -- believed the lies her family told her about him, and wanted to win their favour, so she took the lead in tormenting him, earning a reputation as the greatest villainess of the century.

The tables turned when Karshian's father returned, as he and his father had Latia's entire family sentenced to execution. Just before the execution, Latia's family tried to blame everything on her and revealed that she was an illegitimate child, much to her surprise.

Then, after being executed, Latia regressed three years into the past, when Karshian was still living in her household. She subsequently tries to win his favour this time, rather than that of her family, in order to avoid meeting the same fate as before.

Although Latia's hair looks almost light brownish in the promotional art above, it's more clearly blonde within the story itself, while Karshian's is black.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/i-tamed-the-male-lead-who-tried-to-kill-me).

Comment: Does it have a happy ending? I'm not really in the mood to get invested in something and get sad lol.

Comment: @Mahmoud Salaheddine - I don't know how it ends. I only skimmed the first few chapters, which was enough to confirm the plot points mentioned in the question.